# Prove a function defined on an open ball with radius $1$ is onto a open ball with radius $0.4$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I use $B_{r}$ to denote an open ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$. Consider Euclidean metric and a function $$\begin{align}
f:B_{1} \to \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}$$ with $f(0)=0$ such that $$\begin{align}
\forall x,y\in B_{1}, x\ne y\implies|f(y)-f(x)-(y-x)|<0.1|y-x|  &&(*)
\end{align}$$ I want to show this function is onto ball $B_{0.4}$ . That is, for all $z\in B_{0.4}$ ,there exists an $x$ such that $z=f(x)$

I tried to use $|z|<0.4$ , $f(0)=0$ and $(*)$ . Let $y=0$ and $x\ne 0$ , and use $(*)$ I get $$\begin{align}
|f(x)-x|<0.1|x|<0.1
\end{align}$$ since $x\in B_{1}$ , $|x|<1$ . Since $|f(x)-x|<0.1$ , I can say that $f(x)-x\in B_{0.1}$

Also, I can see the function is injective.

However, I can't relate all the things that I have to prove $f$ is onto $B_{0,4}$, or maybe I miss some hidden information in the problem. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can try showing continuity and use the sequence property.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I'm slightly confused...